# calculating max and joining tables

Tags: subquery

Just need a little help as new to SQL.

I have a table which contains readingtime (records every 4 seconds during the day) and an energy reading. I wanted to know how much energy was used in a day. 
this is the query that i used

```
SELECT date(readingtime), max(energy)-min(energy)as total 
FROM lights_1 
WHERE readingtime between 20140407000000 and 20140409235959 
GROUP BY date(readingtime) LIMIT 0,30;
```

This gave me the desired results for 1 table. I have 4 tables of these lights_2, Lights_3, lights_4 and i would like to display them together and hence match up the reading time so each day has the energy requirements for all for tables with the total. When i try and join tables i get a lot of errors!

Can anyone help.

thanks

Union gives

```
date(readingtime) total
2014-04-07        1244
2014-04-08        1039
2014-04-09        1389
2014-04-07        419
2014-04-08        1102
2014-04-09        482
```

I would like

```
date(readingtime) total_1  total_2
2014-04-07        1244      419
2014-04-08        1039      1039
2014-04-09        1389      1389
```

Comment: Why do you have four tables? This should be one table with an extra column as discriminator.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  date(lights_1.readingtime), 
        max(lights_1.energy)-min(lights_1.energy)as total_1, 
        max(lights_2.energy)-min(lights_2.energy)as total_2
FROM lights_1
join lights_2 on lights_1.readingtime = lights_2.readingtime
WHERE lights_1.readingtime between 20140407000000 and 20140409235959 
GROUP BY date(lights_1.readingtime) LIMIT 0,30
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to `UNION` the tables:

```
SELECT date(readingtime), max(energy)-min(energy)as total 
FROM lights_1 
WHERE readingtime between 20140407000000 and 20140409235959 
GROUP BY date(readingtime) LIMIT 0,30
UNION
SELECT date(readingtime), max(energy)-min(energy)as total 
FROM lights_2 
WHERE readingtime between 20140407000000 and 20140409235959 
GROUP BY date(readingtime) LIMIT 0,30
UNION
SELECT date(readingtime), max(energy)-min(energy)as total 
FROM lights_3 
WHERE readingtime between 20140407000000 and 20140409235959 
GROUP BY date(readingtime) LIMIT 0,30
SELECT date(readingtime), max(energy)-min(energy)as total 
FROM lights_4 
WHERE readingtime between 20140407000000 and 20140409235959 
GROUP BY date(readingtime) LIMIT 0,30;
```

You then will need to pivot the result of this query. I assume you are using MySQL? I could go through and figure out everything for you, but its probably better if you go and learn how to pivot the data to get it the way you want, the following is a good summary!
 http://stratosprovatopoulos.com/web-development/mysql/pivot-a-table-in-mysql/

Comment: I have done this but this lists the data. i want to match up each table with a date.

Comment: Please edit the question to give an example of what you want - its not entirely clear what format you want the data in.

Comment: Also tell us what database system you are using!

Comment: each table has the same readingtime so i need to match these up. otherwise i get a list of each day for Lights_1 and then a list underneath for Lights_2. Does that make sense?

Comment: will do now, sorry

Comment: It sounds like you want to pivot the data so that you have a single row, fist column Date, 2nd column Light1 energy total, 3rd column Light2 energy total etc. Will wait for your edit...

Comment: When i use union i get this.

date(readingtime) total 2014-04-07 1244 2014-04-08 1039 2014-04-09 1389 2014-04-07 419 2014-04-08 1102 2014-04-09 482

I would like this date(readingtime) total_1 total_2 2014-04-07 1244 419 2014-04-08 1039 1102 2014-04-09 1389 482

Comment: sorry. my posts are not showing as i have put them

Comment: when i use union i get this-
date(readingtime) total
2014-04-07        1244
2014-04-08        1039
2014-04-09        1389
2014-04-07        419
2014-04-08        1102
2014-04-09        482 I am trying to send the table i want but it keeps just listing the data?

Comment: Oh right, instead of putting in another answer, please edit your original question, adding on your "answer". Thanks.

Comment: Actually RichardBSmiths solution above should work for you, check that one out (a lot more simple).